# OP removing question after finding answer

Tags: discussion

Well, I was editing one answer in order to make it more helpfull to the OP, and after a while of writing, when I was going to publish the modification, the OP had removed his question due to he had solved his problem.

Should we report this kind of actions?

The question was this » [Android App crashing on startup with fatal exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123935/android-app-crashing-on-startup-with-fatal-exception/24124041#24124041) in case the moderators have access to removed questions.

Comment: It's been undeleted now.

Comment: Your answer has now been upvoted, the question cannot be deleted again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Unless the answer gets downvoted.

Comment: @Servy I guess so ;-)